Implements a READ ID command between the iCE40 HX8K and the AT25SF0818 in Verilog
Question
How can I improve my Verilog code?
Context
Flash Read ID Operation
This project is an implimentation of the Read Manufacturer and Device ID (9Fh) operation initiated by the FPGA device on the iceFUN, to the flash device on the iceFUN.
It is possible to install the necessary pre-requisites for compilation and testing from two sources:

robot electronics webpage

apio


Expected behavior
When this directory is compiled and uploaded to the iceFUN, it sets the CS line to low, and then sends the command hex : 9F to the Flash device from the FPGA on the MOSI line.
The Flash device specification indicates that the response from the Flash to the FPGA on the MISO line should be hex: 1F, 85, 01.
In the flash.v code, the MISO data is routed to the LEDs - which would then light up column 0 with the middle byte: 85, corresponding to the binary 1000 0101.
The LED lights are in on-state when they are set to 0, and off-state when set to 1, so the pattern on the LEDs should read: off on on on on off on off.
The CS line is then be set back to high to signal the operation end.
Code
flash.v:
module main (
    input                    clk,            // Clock input
    output      wire [7:0]   led,            // 8-bit output for LEDs
    output      wire [3:0]   col,            // 4-bit output to select active LED column
    output      wire         cs,             // Chip select signal for SPI
    output      wire         sck,            // Serial clock for SPI
    input                    miso,           // Master In Slave Out (data from SPI device)
    output      wire         mosi            // Master Out Slave In (data to SPI device)
);

    // SYS: System clock counter and control for delay before starting SPI operation
    reg [4:0] clock_counter;                  // 5-bit clock counter

    // LED control registers
    reg [7:0] led_register;                   // Register to store LED output values
    reg [4:0] col_register;                   // Register to store column activation for LEDs
    assign led = led_register;                // Assign register values to output
    assign col = col_register;                // Assign register values to column output

    // SPI: Registers and variables to handle SPI communication
    reg flash_done;                           // Flag indicating SPI operation completion
    reg start_flash;                          // Flag to start SPI flash read operation

    reg cs_register, mosi_register, sck_register;  // Registers for SPI control signals
    assign cs = cs_register;                  // Chip select output assignment
    assign mosi = mosi_register;              // MOSI output assignment
    assign sck = sck_register;                // SCK output assignment

    integer OPERATION_LENGTH;                 // Counter for the length of the SPI operation
    integer SI_PULSE;                         // Counter for outgoing data bits (MOSI)
    integer SO_SAMPLE;                        // Counter for incoming data bits (MISO)
    reg [7:0] OPCODE;                         // 8-bit SPI opcode for the flash memory command
    reg [23:0] RESPONSE_DATA;                 // 24-bit register for storing response from SPI device

    // Initial block for setting default/reset states
    initial begin
        // SYS initialization
        clock_counter <= 0;                   // Reset clock counter
        
        led_register <= 8'b11111111;          // Set all LEDs off
        col_register <= 4'b1110;              // Activate specific LED column (column 0)

        // SPI initialization
        start_flash <= 0;                     // Do not start flash read yet
        flash_done <= 0;                      // SPI operation not completed

        sck_register <= 1;                    // Set SCK to high
        cs_register <= 1;                     // Set chip select to high (inactive)
        mosi_register <= 1;                   // Set MOSI to default state (high)

        OPERATION_LENGTH <= 0;                // Initialize SPI operation length counter
        SI_PULSE <= 0;                        // Reset outgoing data bit counter
        SO_SAMPLE <= 0;                       // Reset incoming data bit counter
        OPCODE <= 8'h9F;                      // Set SPI command for "Read ID" (9Fh)
        RESPONSE_DATA <= 24'b1;               // Initialize response data to a default value
    end

    // Main clock-triggered block for handling operations
    always @(negedge clk) begin
        // Start SPI operation after clock delay
        if (clock_counter < 10) begin
            clock_counter <= clock_counter + 1;          // Increment clock counter
        end else if (clock_counter == 10) begin          // Trigger SPI flash read after 10 cycles
            start_flash <= 1;                            // Start flash read operation
            clock_counter <= clock_counter + 1;          // Increment counter to move to the next state
        end else if (start_flash && flash_done) begin    // Update LEDs with SPI response data
            led_register[7:0] <= RESPONSE_DATA[15:8];    // Set LEDs based on response data
            start_flash <= 0;                            // Reset flash start flag
        end

        // SPI operation handling
        if (start_flash && !flash_done) begin
            cs_register <= 0;                            // Set chip select low (start SPI)
            OPERATION_LENGTH <= OPERATION_LENGTH + 1;    // Increment operation length counter
            
            // Send opcode to SPI device (MOSI)
            if(OPERATION_LENGTH >= 0 && OPERATION_LENGTH <= 7) begin
                SI_PULSE <= SI_PULSE + 1;                // Increment outgoing bit counter
                mosi_register <= OPCODE[7-SI_PULSE];     // Send one bit of opcode (MSB first)
            end
            
            // Receive response from SPI device (MISO)
            if(OPERATION_LENGTH > 7 && OPERATION_LENGTH <= 32) begin
                SO_SAMPLE <= SO_SAMPLE + 1;              // Increment incoming bit counter
                RESPONSE_DATA[23-SO_SAMPLE] <= miso;     // Store incoming bit in response register
            end

            // End SPI operation after receiving full response
            if(OPERATION_LENGTH == 32) begin
                cs_register <= 1;                        // Set chip select high (end SPI)
                flash_done <= 1;                         // Mark SPI operation as complete
            end
        end
    end

    // Clock assignment for SPI clock (SCK) signal
    always @(*) begin
        sck_register <= clk;                             // Set SCK to match system clock
    end

endmodule

output_tb.v:
`timescale 1 ns / 1 ps  // Time scale directive, 1 ns time unit, 1 ps time precision

module output_tb();

    // Declare wires for SPI signals and output values
    wire mosi, sck, cs;             // SPI signals: MOSI, SCK, and CS
    wire [7:0] led;                 // 8-bit wire for LED outputs
    wire [3:0] col;                 // 4-bit wire for column selection (LED control)

    // Declare registers for clock and MISO signal (input to DUT)
    reg clk = 0;                    // Clock signal initialized to 0
    reg miso;                       // MISO input (Master In Slave Out)

    localparam DURATION = 5000;     // Simulation duration parameter (in ns)

    // Clock generation block
    always begin
        #41.67                      // Half-period delay for 12 MHz clock (1 / 12 MHz = 83.33 ns period)
        clk = ~clk;                 // Toggle clock signal every half period
    end

    // Instantiate the main module (Device Under Test - DUT)
    main uut (
        .clk(clk),                  // Connect clock signal
        .led(led),                  // Connect LED output
        .col(col),                  // Connect column selection output
        .cs(cs),                    // Connect chip select (CS) output
        .sck(sck),                  // Connect serial clock (SCK) output
        .mosi(mosi),                // Connect MOSI output
        .miso(miso)                 // Connect MISO input
    );

    // Simulate flash memory behavior (MISO response)
    initial begin
        miso = 8'h00;               // Set MISO to low initially (SO low)

        //// wait for SI operation to finish

        #83.33;                     // Wait 1 clock cycle (83.33 ns for 12 MHz)
        #833.3;                     // Wait 10 clock cycles
        #83.33;                     // Wait 1 more clock cycle
        #666.64;                    // Wait 8 more clock cycles

        //// Simulate incoming flash memory data

        // Simulate hex value 1F (0001 1111 on MISO)
        miso = 8'h00;               // Start with 0
        #83.33;                     // Wait 1 cycle for each bit
        #83.33;
        #83.33;
        miso = 8'hFF;               // Set high (MISO = 1)
        #83.33;
        #83.33;
        #83.33;
        #83.33;
        #83.33;

        // Simulate hex value 85 (1000 0101 on MISO)
        miso = 8'hFF;               // Start with high bit
        #83.33;
        miso = 8'h00;               // Set low bit (MISO = 0)
        #83.33;
        #83.33;
        #83.33;
        #83.33;
        miso = 8'hFF;               // Set high (MISO = 1)
        #83.33;
        miso = 8'h00;               // Set low (MISO = 0)
        #83.33;
        miso = 8'hFF;               // Set high (MISO = 1)
        #83.33;

        // Simulate hex value 01 (0000 0001 on MISO)
        miso = 8'h00;               // Set MISO low for 7 bits
        #83.33;
        #83.33;
        #83.33;
        #83.33;
        #83.33;
        #83.33;
        #83.33;
        miso = 8'hFF;               // Set last bit high (MISO = 1)
        #83.33;
    end

    // VCD dump for waveform analysis
    initial begin
        $dumpfile("output_tb.vcd");  // Create VCD file for simulation waveform output
        $dumpvars(0, output_tb);     // Dump variables from top module (output_tb)
        #(DURATION);                 // Run simulation for specified duration
        $finish;                     // End the simulation
    end

endmodule

iceFUN.pcf:
# Pinout defined by hardware vendor here: https://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/files/iceFUNdoc.pdf

set_io --warn-no-port led[0]        C10
set_io --warn-no-port led[1]        A10
set_io --warn-no-port led[2]        D7
set_io --warn-no-port led[3]        D6
set_io --warn-no-port led[4]        A7
set_io --warn-no-port led[5]        C7
set_io --warn-no-port led[6]        A4
set_io --warn-no-port led[7]        C4
set_io --warn-no-port col[0]        A12
set_io --warn-no-port col[1]        D10
set_io --warn-no-port col[2]        A6
set_io --warn-no-port col[3]        C5
set_io --warn-no-port clk           P7
set_io --warn-no-port cs            P13
set_io --warn-no-port sck           P12
set_io --warn-no-port miso          P11
set_io --warn-no-port mosi          M11


Overview
You have done a good job with:

Partitioning the design and testbench into separate files
Dumping waveforms from your testbench to verify and help debug your design
Using consistent naming style for your signals
Adding meaningful comments
Using consistent indentation

It is great that you provided a complete code example so we can easily run a simulation.
Naming
Conventionally, you would change the name of the main module to flash
in order to match the file name (flash.v).  This comes in handy when using the
simulation command -y option, which is supported by many simulators.
When you have a larger design consisting of several modules and files,
this simplifies the compile command.  This option automatically searches
a directory for modules with matching file names.
Also, the name main is not very descriptive.
Reset
It is common for FPGA flows to initialize registers in an initial
block as your main design is doing.
It is also common to initialize using a reset input signal; this would
make the design portable to other flows (like ASIC flows).
Nonblocking
You used a nonblocking assignment inside the always @(*) block:
    sck_register <= clk;

It is considered good practice to use a blocking assignment inside a combinational logic block
such as this:
    sck_register = clk;

Sensitivity
Using negedge is uncommon in designs; typically, posedge is more conventional.
Partitioning
It is more conventional to split logic into multiple always blocks instead of
cramming all of the code into a single always block as you have done in the main code.
It makes it easier to understand the design.  For example, the block currently has 2
unrelated top-level if/else statements which can easily and naturally be split into separate
blocks.  For example, here is the first block:
always @(negedge clk) begin
    // Start SPI operation after clock delay
    if (clock_counter < 10) begin
        clock_counter <= clock_counter + 1;          // Increment clock counter
    end else if (clock_counter == 10) begin          // Trigger SPI flash read after 10 cycles
        start_flash <= 1;                            // Start flash read operation
        clock_counter <= clock_counter + 1;          // Increment counter to move to the next state
    end else if (start_flash && flash_done) begin    // Update LEDs with SPI response data
        led_register[7:0] <= RESPONSE_DATA[15:8];    // Set LEDs based on response data
        start_flash <= 0;                            // Reset flash start flag
    end
end

Clock domains
You declared 2 clock signals in the design:
input                    clk,            // Clock input
output      wire         sck,            // Serial clock for SPI

Strictly speaking, this means there are 2 clock domains, which usually means you need to pay special attention to timing constraints for synthesis.  However, in your case, the signals are essentially the same.  Apparently, your FPGA design flow handles this gracefully.
Bit width
In the testbench you correctly declared miso as a 1-bit signal:
reg miso;

However, you make assignments to it as if it were an 8-bit signal:
    miso = 8'h00;
    miso = 8'hFF;

This is confusing and misleading.  You should make simpler assignments like:
    miso = 0;
    miso = 1;

Parameter
In the testbench, you have several constant delay values which seem to be related to each other:
41.67, 83.33, 833.3, etc.

It is better to give names to these values using a parameter.  Then you can use expressions
for the delays:
parameter CLK_PERIOD = 83.33; // ns (12MHz)
always #(CLK_PERIOD/2.0) clk = ~clk;
#(10 * CLK_PERIOD);

This has the side benefit of making the code self-explanatory so that you don't need
to add and maintain comments like:
// Wait 10 clock cycles

This also eliminates repetitious code like:
    #83.33;
    #83.33;
    #83.33;
    #83.33;
    #83.33;

It becomes one line of code:
#(5 * CLK_PERIOD);

It would be even better if you drove the miso signal in the testbench relative to a clock edge instead of using # delays.  Also, you should use nonblocking assignments (<=).  Since the signal is synchronous to the design, it should be driven in the same way as you drive synchronous signals in the design.  For example, in the testbench:
repeat (5) @(negedge clk);
miso <= 0;
repeat (3) @(negedge clk);
miso <= 1;

Not only does this make the testbench code easier to understand, but it also avoids Verilog simulation race conditions.
The next step would be to encapsulate a data byte as a Verilog task and drive the input that way.
SystemVerilog
SystemVerilog (SV) features were added to the language nearly 20 years ago, and
all tool chains support these features to some degree.  Annoyingly,
many tools have these features disabled by default, which means you
may need to enable the features with some sort of tool settings.  Refer to
your simulation/synthesis documentation.
Using SV syntax has its advantages.
In the main code, you can replace always with always_ff.  Not only does it
convey the design intent better, but it also provides built-in checking
if your tool has the capability to do so.
You can replace the constant:
8'b11111111

with the much simpler:
'1

This scales better if your signal width changes, say from 8 bits to 16 bits.
Here is a simpler way to drive the miso input in the testbench, employing a task as well as SV features (bit, int, etc.):
bit miso; // MISO input (Master In Slave Out)

initial begin
    repeat (22) @(negedge clk);
    drive_miso(8'h1f);
    drive_miso(8'h85);
    drive_miso(8'h01);
end

task drive_miso (bit [7:0] data);
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) begin
        @(negedge clk);
        miso <= data[i];
    end
endtask

